# Why is the Chern Number Invariant under A Continuously Shrinking of the Structure Group?

Tags: lie-groups, homotopy-theory, cohomology, chern-classes, chern-simons-theory

In Witten's paper [Three Dimensional Gravity Revisited](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.3359.pdf) and [Quantization of Chern-Simons Theory with Complex Gauge Group](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1104202513), he used a fact that for a principal $G$-bundle, the quantization of the Chern number is reduced to the case of its maximal compact subgroup.

For example, the reason why the Chern-level $k$ of the $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$-Chern-Simons theory

$$S[A]=\frac{k}{4\pi}\int_{M}\mathrm{Tr}\left(A\wedge dA+\frac{2}{3}A\wedge A\wedge A\right)$$

takes integer values ($k\in\mathbb{Z}$) is reduced to the case of the $\mathrm{SU}(2)$-Chern-Simons theory, because the group manifold $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ can be continuously shunk to $\mathrm{SU}(2)$.

Can anybody tell me how to prove this? Are there any references showing the proof that are easy to understand for physics students?

Comment: What is the mathematical translation or definition of "the quantization of (...) is reduced to the case of..." into maths?

Comment: @Qfwfq it is saying that the reason why $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ is reduced to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite understand the quantization part of the question.

However, the characteristic numbers are always given by pairing products of the (characteristic) cohomology classes with the fundamental class of the manifold $M$, say. Such classes are pullbacks of classes in the cohomology of $BG$, where $G$ is the structure group (where $M\to BG$ classifies the bundle).

Now,  The cohomology of $BG$ is homotopy invariant in the sense that if $G\to H$ is a homomorphism which is also a homotopy equivalence of underlying spaces, then the map $H^\ast(BH) \to H^\ast(BG)$ is an isomorphism.

If we take $H := SL_n(\Bbb C)$ and $G = SU_n(\Bbb C)$, we get the statement you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you John. Do you think it is true for $H=SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $G=U(1)$? I asked this question in another post https://mathoverflow.net/q/307352/120604

Comment: yes, it is. The map $SO(2) \to SL_2(\Bbb R)$ is a homotopy equivalence. They are both homotopy equivalent to a circle, as is $U(1)$.

Comment: Would you please give me a reference where I can study the details?

Comment: So, in the end, what was the statement the OP was looking for?

Comment: @Qfwfq John Klein already answered my question.

Comment: @New Student: Probably. But I think I am missing some link like: is the coh class of the Chern-Simons form $[\alpha]$ (where $\alpha$ is your integrand) a char class of some bundle? Assuming "yes", then: $[\alpha]=f^*[\alpha_G]$ for $f$ a classif map and $\alpha_G$ a cohom. class on $BG$, when you express $[\alpha_G]$ as $\pi^*([\alpha_H])$ via the isom $\pi^*$ on coh given by the retraction $\pi:G\to H$, can you say anything about $\alpha_H$? And can you say something beside $\int_M \alpha = \int_M f^*\pi^*(\alpha_H)$? I just don't follow the hypothesis, nor the thesis of the statement.

Comment: The Chern-Simons form is the secondary class of the second Chern-class. The "quantization" (meaning discretization) of its level $k$ is related to the the fact that the second Chern-class belongs to an integral cohomology. So Mr John Klein showed me that bundles are classified by that $GB$ thing, which I am still struggling with. I don't think you need to worrying about what $\alpha_{H}$ looks like. I am only asking whether $k$ is quantized (i.e. $k\in\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: More generally, every Lie group $G$ with finitely many components has a maximal compact subgroup $K$ and the inclusion $K \to G$ is a deformation retraction and therefore a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: @NewStudent There is standard place to look: (1) Milnor and Stasheff's Characteristic classes. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201368/classifying-spaces-of-topological-groups-whose-underlying-spaces-are-homotopy-eq for information about the statement I made.  Note too that the cohomology of the infinite Grassmannian (cf. Milnor-Stasheff) coincides with the cohomology of the space $BG$ for $G=\Bbb GL_n(\Bbb C)$.